# Cannot register device with web service URL

Tags: web-services, ios6, passbook

Before, I used webservice URL: `http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/` and everything works well, but now I change this webservice URL to `http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/webService/`
 and I cannot register device like before. I also get this error:
 `"[2013-04-26 10:36:29 +0700] Register task (for device 28fe8f689b0df31c788a2e311e0c6ee4, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 0001; with web service url http://192.168.1.202:8888/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Authentication failure",`
 
how to get this webservice URL works ?

Comment: now I can change something and it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check $request = explode("/", substr(@$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0));

and change $request[4] === "devices" and change next and next !